# What is different in between |sin(x)| and sin|x|?

Tags: trigonometry

what is different in between |sin(x)| and sin|x|?
I checked two graphs and  |sin(x)| is graph 
[image: |sin(x)|]
Idk what is graph sin|x|?

whether it is the correct notation?

Comment: It's the very same graph of $\;\sin x\;$ for $\;x\ge0\;$, and then you mirror-copy it for $\;x<0\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the graph of $y=\sin (|x|)$, here it is.  It is worth thinking about why this differs from $y=|\sin(x)|$  Why couldn't the same software you used make this graph?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

The graph of $y=\sin|x|$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$ axis ( because $|-x|=|x|$) and it the same as $y=\sin x$ for $x\ge 0$.